# Writing a parser for a binary message format

Tags: java, parsing, design-patterns

I need to develop a parser for a binary message exchange format i.e., a message parser which parses a binary message into an java object representation. I would like to ask what useful patterns could be used to implement a parser in a most flexible way. Could anybody describe this in a nutshell or provide resources to read?

Comment: https://github.com/jparsec/jparsec

Comment: You could maybe try reading about the way [Google protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding) are designed (or alternatively just use them!)

Comment: Depends what you mean by "parser", Usually, a [parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) reads text, not binary data.

Answer (score 2):

Since youre trying to read binary data and transform it into Java Object, there are many approaches, but first thing first, you must know the structure/protocol of your binary.

The pattern I show you bellow is the style that I (if I were you) will use for this scenario.

Make sure you have an input stream that will stream out your binary data. If what you have is a byte array, Make a ByteArrayInputStream.

In your objects graph, each node/object should implement something like parseIn(InputStream s) method.

```
public class Parent extends ArrayList<Child> {
    int age;
    // ... more code here
    public void parseIn(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        // .. logic to read the stream into this instance.
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
        this.age = dis.readInt();

        // .. if necessary
        Child c = new Child();
        c.parseIn(InputStream is);
        this.add(c);
    }
    // ... more code here
}

public class Child {
    int height;
    short weight;
    Date birthdate;
    public void parseIn(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        // .. logic to read the stream into this instance.
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
        height = dis.readInt();
        weight = dis.readShort();
        birthdate = new Date(dis.readLong());
    }
}
```

So, when you obtain your stream, you simply

```
InputStream stream = this.getInputStream(); 
Parent p = new Parent();
parent.parseIn(stream);
```

And so on and so forth.

Some times, you need to read the underlying stream for some hint you need to read forward. For example when reading a string data in the binary stream. Either you keep reading byte-by-byte until you find a terminator byte (as of C's style 0 termination character). Or to provide the string length on the first byte and then read a byte array of that length.

I hope you get the Idea. And I hope it helps.

Comment: Look out: Use DataInputStream only if the input stream has been produced by a java DataOutputStream.

Comment: I'm not a fan of the lack of final fields in this solution.

Comment: Java uses BigEndian when it read/write number bigger than 8 bit. And DataOutputStream is using bigendian for this purpose CMIIW. IETF has made the internetworking to be BigEndian (RFC 1700) ... I understand that there might be a case for LittleEndian, but I think, ByteBuffer have some solution around LittleEndian. Anyhow, the snippets above is only to express the pattern. Not going to detail about how you read the byte by byte in term of little/big endian. Thus the usage of DataInputStream can be used or replaced with the most suitable case.